# Expected bytes, HTTPResponse found

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, messenger

I want to use linebot to make an object detection application, and when I retrieve the url which is a http type, the system called an error.

```
 [2022-11-23 19:13:12,335] ERROR in app: Exception on /callback [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\officiallandprice\myproject\myenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\officiallandprice\myproject\myenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\officiallandprice\myproject\myenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\officiallandprice\myproject\myenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "part1deploy_3.py", line 55, in callback
    handler.handle(body, signature)
  File "C:\officiallandprice\myproject\myenv\lib\site-packages\linebot\webhook.py", line 259, in handle
    self.__invoke_func(func, event, payload)
  File "C:\officiallandprice\myproject\myenv\lib\site-packages\linebot\webhook.py", line 271, in __invoke_func
    func(event)
  File "part1deploy_3.py", line 201, in handle_content_message
    text_detected1=text_detected(user.user_id)
  File "part1deploy_3.py", line 81, in text_detected
    image = vision.Image(content=input_file)
  File "C:\officiallandprice\myproject\myenv\lib\site-packages\proto\message.py", line 604, in __init__
    super().__setattr__("_pb", self._meta.pb(**params))
TypeError: expected bytes, HTTPResponse found
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2022 19:13:12] "POST /callback HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I do not have ideas which part of the code below requires a byte type file to make a detection(the PIL module?).

Is it necessary to change to the byte type, when it comes to an object detection?

```
def text_detected(user_id):
    input_file=urllib.request.urlopen (
      'https://storage.googleapis.com/
       img_platecapture/{}.jpg'.format(user_id))

    image = vision.Image(content=input_file)
    response = vision_client.text_detection(image=image)    

    if response.error.message:
        raise Exception(
            '{}\nFor more info on error messages, check: '
            'https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors'.format(
                response.error.message))

    img = Image.open(input_file)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("simsun.ttc", 18)

    for text in response.text_annotations[1::]:
        ocr = text.description
        draw.text((bound.vertices[0].x-25, bound.vertices[0].y-25),ocr,fill=(255,0,0),font=font)
        
        draw.polygon(
            [
                bound.vertices[0].x,
                bound.vertices[0].y,
                bound.vertices[1].x,
                bound.vertices[1].y,
                bound.vertices[2].x,
                bound.vertices[2].y,
                bound.vertices[3].x,
                bound.vertices[3].y,
            ],
            None,
            'yellow',
        
            )

    texts=response.text_annotations
    a=str(texts[0].description.split())

    b=re.sub(u"([^\u4e00-\u9fa5\u0030-u0039])","",a)
    b1="".join(b)
    print("偵測到的地址為:",b1)  
    return b1
   
@handler.add(MessageEvent, message=ImageMessage)
def handle_content_message(event):
    message_content = line_bot_api.get_message_content(event.message.id)
    user = line_bot_api.get_profile(event.source.user_id)

    data=b''
    for chunk in message_content.iter_content():
       data+= chunk
   
    global bucket_name   
    bucket_name = 'img_platecapture'
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(f'{user.user_id}.jpg')
    blob.upload_from_string(data)
    text_detected1=text_detected(user.user_id) ####Here's the problem
    
    line_bot_api.reply_message(
        event.reply_token,
        messages=TextSendMessage(
            text=text_detected1
    ))
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is provide the complete traceback. This will improve the quality of answers you receive.

Comment: @Michael Ruth thanx for the reminding

Comment: This error is generated by the line: `image = vision.Image(content=input_file)`. This is because `urllib.request.urlopen` returns an `HTTPResponse` not a filename or file object. You need to get the file from the response and pass it to `Image.open()`.